# Decrease vertical space before horizontal line

Tags: line-spacing

I am writing my CV. I wrote:

```
{\bf MEMBERSHIP}\\
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
                 \begin{itemize}
                 \item item1
                 \item item2
                 \end{itemize}
```

I want to decrease the vertical distance between "MEMBERSHIP" and the line. I mean, I want whole part after MEMBERSHIP(the line and the items) be shifted up TOGETHER.
Thank you

Comment: please answer my question soon since I have to send my CV in 2 hours!!

Answer (score 4):

`\bf`  shouldn't really be used in latex

probably

```
\textbf{MEMBERSHIP}

\vspace{-5pt}
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
```

does what you want although really such space and font commands should always be hidden in a sectioning macro so the document looks like

```
\mysection{MEMBERSHIP}
```